# CFoutput Query Looping but addind html only every third loop

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to figure out how to line my contact boxes up to fit properly. The problem I am running into is with my loop using the cfoutput query. I need to start a row only every three loops. This is never a set number and pulls straight from the database. How can I have `<div class="row">` show up the first loop then skip the 2nd and 3rd but come back on the 4th loop then skip 5  and 6 and continue so on?

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
      <cfoutput query="grab_contacts">
        <div class="row">
        <!-- Insert Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=#grab_contacts.employee_number#">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/#grab_contacts.picture#">
                            <cfif len(grab_contacts.phone_extension)>
                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension #grab_contacts.phone_extension#</div>
                            </cfif>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong>#grab_contacts.firstname# #grab_contacts.lastname#</strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>#grab_contacts.position#</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> #grab_contacts.department# Department<br>
                            MCTC #grab_contacts.branch# Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here --></cfoutput>
          </div>
       </div>
```

Rows should look like:
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9

EDIT: Still Having Issues

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
      <cfoutput query="grab_contacts">
        <cfif CurrentRow mod 3 eq 1>
            <div class="row">
        </cfif>
        <!-- Insert Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=#grab_contacts.employee_number#">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/#grab_contacts.picture#">
                            <cfif len(grab_contacts.phone_extension)>
                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension #grab_contacts.phone_extension#</div>
                            </cfif>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong>#grab_contacts.firstname# #grab_contacts.lastname#</strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>#grab_contacts.position#</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> #grab_contacts.department# Department<br>
                            MCTC #grab_contacts.branch# Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
        <cfif CurrentRow mod 3 eq 1>
            </div>
        </cfif>
          </cfoutput>
       </div>
```

How rows look now:
1
2 3 4 
5 6 7 
8 9

Comment: tried css tricks just tried the example below which is very close but I keep running into issues

Comment: (Edit) I meant before you posted the question ;-)  A quick google search should have turned up a ton of examples, all using `MOD` , like Tim mentioned. If you are still running into problems, please [edit] your question to append your current code - and an example of the bad output. So we can help you to get it working properly.

Comment: first row only has 1 then the rest is perfect

Comment: @Leigh any assistance possible ? I am still fumbling this around

Comment: (Edit) I think the MOD logic is slightly off for what you are trying to do. I have to take off, but try starting with something like this logic: http://trycf.com/gist/8d2b28bd5b85ffcc3df1/acf11?theme=monokai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<cfif CurrentRow mod 3 eq 1>
    <div class="row">
</cfif>
```

and then

```
<cfif CurrentRow mod 3 eq 0 or CurrentRow eq grab_contacts.recordCount>
    </div>
</cfif>
```

at the end as well.

Comment: this is super close but its messing only the first row up

Comment: im trying to make rows of three

Comment: trying to make it like the rows I posted above

Comment: when I tried this the first 1 is the first row and then it starts doing what it is supposed to do

Comment: Might double check the closing `</div>` logic. The `mod` comparison looks a little off.

Comment: Leigh, you're right. I mistyped; the logic needs to be different for the closing tag.

Comment: Additionally, you should probably add some logic for when the number of rows does not divide evenly by three.

Comment: Yep, checking against the recordCount as well would do it.